# beautifulsoup 4: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I crawled the following page:

http://www.nasa.gov/topics/earth/features/plains-tornadoes-20120417.html

But I got Segmentation fault (core dumped) when calling: BeautifulSoup(page_html), where page_html is the content from requests library. Is this a bug for BeautifulSoup? Is there any way to get around with this? Even approach like try...except would help me to get my code running. Thanks in advance.

The code is as following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

toy_url = 'http://www.nasa.gov/topics/earth/features/plains-tornadoes-20120417.html'
res = requests.get(toy_url,headers={"USER-Agent":"Firefox/12.0"})
page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: Please show the code you used so it can be reproduced (I can't reproduce this with urllib2 and BeautifulSoup).

Comment: @DavidRobinson The code is appended now. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Install `lxml`. The default HTML parser from py2.7 won't parse this page because of a wrong tag... BTW, py3.2 works fine. (Can't make it segfault)

Comment: Strangely, this code works fine for me too (no segfault). I'm using Python 2.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with the latest version of `bs4` and `requests` (just installed now).

Comment: @JBernardo I originally use 'lxml' with BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml') in python2.7, but it got segment. Unfortunately, I cannot use py3.2 now as potential it may be incompatible with other parts of my code.

Comment: @DavidRobinson mine is ubuntu 12.04 with python2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is caused by [a bug in lxml](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/984936), which is fixed in lxml 2.3.5. You can upgrade lxml, or use Beautiful Soup with the html5lib or the HTMLParser parser.

Comment: I hit a similar error "Segmentation fault: 11" upgrading lxml from 3.4.1-py27_0 to 3.4.3-py27_0 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug.  Shouldn't be able to segfault this way.  I can reproduce (4.0.1):

```
>>> import bs4, urllib2
>>> url = "http://www.nasa.gov/topics/earth/features/plains-tornadoes-20120417.html"
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
Segmentation fault
```

After some bisecting, it looks to be caused by the DOCTYPE:

```
>>> page[:page.find(">")+1]
'<!DOCTYPE "xmlns:xsl=\'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\'">'
```

And a crude hack allows bs4 to parse it:

```
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page[page.find(">")+1:])
>>> soup.find_all("a")[:3]
[<a href="/home/How_to_enable_Javascript.html" target="_blank">› Learn How</a>, <a href="#maincontent">Follow this link to skip to the main content</a>, <a class="nasa_logo" href="/home/index.html"><span class="hide">NASA - National Aeronautics and Space Administration</span></a>]
```

Someone who knows more might be able to see what's really going on, but that might help you get started, anyway.

Comment: It depends on the parser bs4 is using: `HTMLParseError: bad end tag: u"</scr' + 'ipt>", at line 138, column 93`... `lxml` and Python3.2 default html parser works fine

Comment: Thanks DSM. But I need a more general solution. As my crawler is not only targeting the nasa.gov website.

Comment: I was hitting the same problem while parsing HTML from the Wikipedia MW API. This works just fine, quick and dirty. Thanks.