# Debugging exit code 139 in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, beautifulsoup

I have run into an issue with a Python program that I am at a loss for how to debug. My program uses BeautifulSoup to parse page after page, and at some point it dies with exit code 139, without an error message (even if run via the debugger). As far as I can tell 139 means segmentation fault, which does not give me much to go on. The issue is non-deterministic and does not happen quickly, so it's hard to reproduce. Repeatedly handing BeautifulSoup the same HTML does not cause the issue, even if I use HTML that I've seen cause the issue in the past. Is there anything I can do to debug the issue?

It is not the same issue as discussed in [beautifulsoup 4: Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323469/beautifulsoup-4-segmentation-fault-core-dumped). That issue is deterministic, unlike mine, and I have no trouble parsing the web page discussed in that (now somewhat dated) question.

Comment: Bash converts the exit status of a process that dies from signal number N into exit status 128+N.  Since SIGSEGV is signal number 11, you're correct that 139 indicates that something run by a Bash process died from a segmentation fault.  That, though, is the easy bit.  I've no idea how to help you with the rest.  However, maybe you can work out which part of your code invokes a shell to run some other program that is crashing (occasionally) for you.

Comment: I posted [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544188/how-can-i-find-out-what-subprocesses-my-python-program-is-running) on how I can figure out what subprocesses are running when my program dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the parser I use to `html.parser` seems to have resolved the issue.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
```